# How to create custom model events laravel 5.1?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I want to create a custom model event in laravel 5.1.

For e.x. when an Articles category is updated i want to make an event and listen to it.

```
$article = Article::find($id);
$article->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
// fire an event here
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Eloquent Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events) (do not confuse with Laravel Events).

```
public function boot()
{
    Article::updated(function ($user) {
        // do some stuff here
    });
}
```

Comment: Sure but how to create a custom eloquent event to fire only when the category is updated.

Comment: Look, if you have categories, you should have model for it anyway (which is in one-to-one or one-to-many relation with `Article`), so you do not need 'custom events'. You really need to learn relations: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Yeah i know how relations work but what im trying to do is when some things are trying to change on the Article E.x category_id, status, etc..

i want to log them and for that i need some custom events anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: I would suggest using `self` or `static`  over hard coding the class name, this is because when IoC drops in an instance from an interface, the former will instantiate the correct object (or override) where as the latter (your suggestion) would not use the class intended and _could_ cause an ambiguous bug/error.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to look into Observers to make this more reusable and single-responsible, though a  starting point would be something alike:

```
public function boot()
{
    self::updated(function ($model) {
        if (array_key_exists('category_id', $model->getDirty())) {
            // Log things here
        }
    });
}
```

Laravel will populate a 'dirty' array which contains modified fields.  You can detect when a certain field has changed using this.

You also have:

```
$model->getOriginal('field_name') // for this field value (originally)
$model->getOriginal() // for all original field values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Attribute Events](https://attribute.events/) to fire an event when the category_id attribute changes:

```
class Article extends Model
{
    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'category_id:*' => ArticleCategoryChanged::class,
    ];
}
```